# Multi-page tcolorbox with complete box on each page

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

In my document preamble, I have:

```
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
```

In the body, I have a `tcolorbox` called thus:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,rounded corners, parbox=false]
```

This is a very large box running into multiple pages. With the current settings, the box continues on the next page but does not close on each page.

How do I get the box to close on each page?

Comment: Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Have you checked the tcolorbox manual about partial boxes? It is very helpful in explaining those concepts.

Comment: As far as I know, neither `enhanced` nor `enhanced jigsaw` allow for bottom or or top rules for the middle boxes and for bottomrule on the first, or top rule on the first box.

Answer (score 15):

**Update (09/Feb/2023)**

This is an alternative to my original answer (below) which is easier to apply. At least we don't need to know `TiKZ` commands to solve the problem.

The `enhanced` skin applied to broken boxes produces unclosed fragments but a closed box for not broken ones. We can change this behaviour with options `skin first`, `skin middle` and `skin last` which allow to decide how all fragments will look like modifying the default design.

In this case the solution consists in applying `enhanced` to all three options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    enhanced, 
    breakable,
    skin first=enhanced,
    skin middle=enhanced,
    skin last=enhanced,
    ]{}
    \lipsum[1-15]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

**Original answer:**

You can hide the original frame (`frame hidden`) and draw an `overlay`-ed frame according your taste:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
    enhanced, 
    breakable,
    frame hidden,
    overlay broken = {
        \draw[line width=1mm, red, rounded corners]
        (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);},
    ]{}
    \lipsum[1-15]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh damn, you beat me by some minutes :-( ... (+1)... I wonder, why this is not incorporated already as possible option for broken boxes in `tcolorbox`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Did you think the same solution? About including as a possible option, we can always fill a suggestion in [`tcolorbox` development site](https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox).

Comment: It was basically the same solution, apart from the red color of the frame ;-) Thanks for suggesting the link to the github site

Comment: do you know if this solution was reported upstream the development site? and Deshmukh, you should mark the question as answered I guess.