# Rounded corners on breakable tcolorbox + customized title

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox

I am trying to adapt the solution given in this thread.

[Multi-page tcolorbox with complete box on each page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400330/multi-page-tcolorbox-with-complete-box-on-each-page)

What I am looking for is to have a nice tcolorbox for my theorems that is breakable and such that on the bottom end of the first page and on the upper end of the second page, the frame has rounded corners.
(Additionnaly I would like to be able to personnalize the title with the name of the theorem when it has one but maybe I should post it as a different question).

I think one difficulty is that the title is shifted on the main frame of the box. This is what I am using right now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{theo}{enhanced,title=Théorème,breakable,
        overlay first={\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay last={\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
        colframe=magenta!60!white,colback=magenta!10!white,
        arc=1mm,colbacktitle=magenta!10!white,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=magenta!50!black,
        attach boxed title to top left=
        {xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm},
        boxed title style={size=small,colframe=magenta!60!white, colback=white!65!magenta}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}{}{}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{theo
\end{document}
```

If anyone car help with that I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `theorems` and similar constructions is better to use `\newtcbtheorem` command. This is what I've done in this solution. This box declaration creates a `theo` box with two mandatory parameters, the first one is a particular title and the second a label suffix (not used in this example).

About the complete frame for broken boxes, you can fix which skin to use with `skin first`, `skin middle` and `skin last` options. As you want a complete frame with rounded corners, all three are fixed to `enhanced`. The initial `enhanced` option fixes them to be broken and these options restores again to unbroken aspect.

As `many` already loads `skins` library, you don't need to add it as option when loading the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{theo}{Theorem}{enhanced, breakable, 
            skin first=enhanced,
            skin middle=enhanced,
            skin last=enhanced,
        colframe=magenta!60!white,colback=magenta!10!white,
        arc=1mm,colbacktitle=magenta!10!white,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=magenta!50!black,
        attach boxed title to top left=
        {xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm},
        boxed title style={size=small,colframe=magenta!60!white, colback=white!65!magenta}
    }{theo}

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}{My first theorem}{}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{theo}

\begin{theo}{My second theorem}{}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thank you! That looks really better, I have to study this package one day because I do not get what is the use of the first enhanced then.

Comment: @WrabbitW the first `enhanced` adds all possibilities to change the aspect of boxes, like the `boxed title` that you use. But this option also decides how parts of broken boxes looks like, and this is what can be changed with skin first, middle and last option.

Answer (score 0):

From your post, I could understand that you don't want the bottom rule of the first page and the top rule of the second page, if my understanding is correct, then it was the default setting in `tcolorbox`, the problem is because of you defined the `overlay first` and `overlay middle` and `overlay last`, just comment it and the output comes as you expected, and the modified `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[skins,many]{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{theo}{enhanced,title=Theorem,breakable,
%        overlay first={\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);},
%        overlay middle={\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.south west)--(frame.south east);\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
%        overlay last={\draw[line width=.5mm, magenta!70!white] (frame.north west)--(frame.north east);},
        colframe=magenta!60!white,colback=magenta!10!white,
        arc=1mm,colbacktitle=magenta!10!white,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,coltitle=magenta!50!black,
        attach boxed title to top left=
        {xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm},
        boxed title style={size=small,colframe=magenta!60!white, colback=white!65!magenta}
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}{}{}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Actually what I would like is to have both bottom rule and top rule at the break but I would like the corners to be rounded.